# Google Sheets Api v4 getBatch() range limit

Tags: spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get data from a spreadsheet (59 sheets) using this get request:

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values:batchGet

I have noticed that 40 ranges (sheets) is the limit before I get illegal request.

Does anyone know if this is normal behaviour and where it is documented?

Comment: Nope, the only specific limit specified in Sheets API is found in [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits). Either this is an implicit limit or something's wrong with your request.

Comment: Thanks for that @noogui. I just found out that the issue has to do with the length of the url request. I shortened the name of the sheets and I could fit more into the request.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the issue has to do with the length of the url request. I shortened the name of the sheets and I could fit more into the request.

Comment: Good thing you found out :)